# Is there a way to update a table using random values in each row in a table with multiple primary keys?

Tags: postgresql

We have a databade in postgresql ver 11.7 on the pgAdmin4 which has a table with 3 primary keys .We want to update each row with a random value between 1 and 10 .
We have found the desirable elements but we need a way to update only 1 row each time 
the conditions are as follow :

1)The subjects much be in a specific semester which can be found in the table called "Courses"

2)then we must find the amkas of students who are registered ( register_status = 'approved')
and we need to upade the table called "Register" with random exam_grades with those conditions assuming the exam_grade is null

```
Update "Register" SET exam_grade = (SELECT floor(random() * 10 + 1)::int)  WHERE course_code  IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT course_code FROM "Course" WHERE typical_year = 2 AND typical_season = 'spring'  ) AND register_status = 'approved' AND exam_grade is  null ;
```

Just that .Somehow we need the update to just be used on only one row and then just use a for loop to take it one by one.If there is any other information i should include ,please tell me

So the tables are as follows 
Register: 
  amka(PK)   serial_number(PK)   course_code(PK)   exam_grade   final_grade   lab_grade   register_status

---

```
    19                   5   ΕΝΕ 501           null         null          null        proposed            
    13                  15   ΤΗΛ 417           2            2             null        fail                
    13                  15   ΤΗΛ 411           10           8.4           null        pass                
    47                  22   ΜΠΔ 433           6            null          9           approved
```

:

Course:

course_code(PK)   typical_year   typical_season    units   ects   weight   obligatory

---

ΑΓΓ 201                      2   winter                2      4        1   true
  ΜΑΘ 201                      1   winter                4      6      1.5   true
  ΜΑΘ 208                      1   winter                3      5      1.5   false

The results that i want are

mka(PK)   serial_number(PK)   course_code(PK)   exam_grade   final_grade   lab_grade   register_status

---

```
   19                   5   ΕΝΕ 501           random       null          null        approved            
   13                  15   ΤΗΛ 417           random       2             null        approved            
   13                  15   ΤΗΛ 411           random       8.4           null        approved            
   47                  22   ΜΠΔ 433           random       null          9           approved
```

new random in each row 
but i only get 1 number which fills all of them
i hope with this edit things became clearer

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances getting a satisfactory answer. In particular post table descriptions for all referenced tables and sample data, as formatted text (or insert statemants) - **no images**  and the expected output of that data. Use [this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to format your text , then post it into your question and place ``` before and after it.

Comment: @Belayer i dont think that posting the tables will actually help but since you want it sure.JUst give me a sec cause there aere a lot of columns